# How to save my GridView array Images to Storage?

Tags: android

I made a array for my images to display them in GridView list . The problem is it's taking a lot of memory,the scroll is slow(not smooth) and keep force closing every time. after i checked solutions I saw that I need to save them to storage and then use them in app. but it didn't work. can someone help me how to do it ?

this is my adapter code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context mContext;
// Keep all Images in array
public Integer[] mThumbIds = { R.drawable.d, R.drawable.t,
        R.drawable.e, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.r,
        R.drawable.asdt, R.drawable.asd, R.drawable.a,
        //... etc

};

public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
        // keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(Resources res, int resId,
        int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

    // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize=4;
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);

    // Calculate inSampleSize
    options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth,
            reqHeight);

    // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
}

// Constructor
public ImageAdapter(Context c) {
    mContext = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mThumbIds.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mThumbIds[position];
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ImageView imageView;
    imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    imageView.setImageBitmap(decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(
            imageView.getResources(), mThumbIds[position], 100, 100));
    imageView.buildDrawingCache(isEmpty());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(
            (getScreenWidth() / 3), (getScreenWidth() / 3)));
    return imageView;

}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public int getScreenWidth() {
    int columnWidth;
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();

    final Point point = new Point();
    try {
        display.getSize(point);
    } catch (java.lang.NoSuchMethodError ignore) { // Older device
        point.x = display.getWidth();
        point.y = display.getHeight();
    }
    columnWidth = point.x;
    return columnWidth;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I just use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) and let it do all the work for me.

```
Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.whatever).into(imageView);
```

and done.

Comment: in getView() instead of setImageBitmap. You can use the library to resize the images if need be to save storage space.